# IPhone X - Height of bottom bar

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

[image: Botom bar]

The bottom bar of my app is having issues when I test it on iPhone simulater. "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" option is already enabled. The height of bottom bar looks fine but when I click on an icon, background for that selected icon should be all white but it is not the case yet. I am using a Tab bar Controller.

Also, the text and labels in my view are pixeled.

My code for this custom tab bar controller is following

```
   super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green: 209/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1)


    // set selected icon background color
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

    // remove default border
    tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
    tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2

    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:65/255, green: 174/255, blue: 168/255, alpha: 1)

    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Are you using a tab bar controller? You should be. Why are you playing with the tab bar's frame? You should not be.

Comment: yes, I am using a tab bar controller.

Comment: OK but then the frame of the tab bar is not yours to play with. You should not be subclassing tab bar controller. Everything you need to do can be done from elsewhere.